# SQL-MS Access - Expression not included on multiple left join query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I recently started the process of learning SQL and have hit my first wall. I have three tables in our database- Chart of Accounts (ChartAccts), Modified Transaction Detail (ModTD), and Beginning Trial Balance (TB_Beg). I am trying to create a query that shows all accounts and their names in the Chart of Accounts, the Beginning Balance for each account from the Trial Balance, and the amount column from the Modified Transaction Detail. They are all linked via the account numbers within each of the tables.

I am currently getting this "Your query does not include the specified expression 'Account_Num' as part of an aggregate function." when attempting to run this code:

```
SELECT A.Account_Num, A.Account_Name, NZ(Sum(B.[Amount ]),0) AS [Sum Of Amount], C.Amount
FROM ((ChartAccts AS A)
LEFT JOIN ModTD AS B ON A.[Account_Num] = B.[Account (Line): Number ])
LEFT JOIN TB_Beg AS C ON A.[Account_Num] = C.[Account #];
```

I feel like my problem must have something to do with the ON statements but I have been starting at this for so long that I don't think I am going to identify the issue despite how simple it must be. Any/all advice is appreciated!

Comment: If are aggregating one column (e.g. `Sum(B.[Amount ])`) all the other columns should show up in the `GROUP BY` clause (that you should include).

Comment: Wow - I feel so silly. This was exactly what I was missing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "GROUP BY" clause. When you use an SQL aggregate function (e.g., Max(), Min(), Sum(), ...) you must include all the fields that are not inside the expression of the argument of an SQL aggregate function in the GROUP BY clause. Aditionally, you cannot use the same field inside and outside the aggregate function: you cannot aggregate and not aggregate at the same time.

What I think you want is:

```
SELECT A.Account_Num, A.Account_Name, NZ(Sum(B.[Amount ]),0) AS [Sum Of Amount]
FROM
     (    ChartAccts AS A
      LEFT JOIN 
          ModTD AS B 
      ON A.[Account_Num] = B.[Account (Line): Number ])
LEFT JOIN
     TB_Beg AS C 
ON A.[Account_Num] = C.[Account #]
GROUP BY A.Account_Num, A.Account_Name ;
```

You may want to check the Query "F_Select_w_group_by_aggreg" and related "F_Select_*" queries from the database of examples that you can download from [LightningGuide.net](https://LightningGuide.net).

Finally, be careful with the Nz() function, because when invoked from SQL it always returns a string. This can create problems if you use this fragment of code as part of a larger Query. You may want to enclose the Nz() function in a type-conversion function, or use an Iif() function instead.

Comment: " you cannot aggregate and not aggregate at the same time."  -- that is a fantastic explanation. kudos.